# Sitecore Forms Extension 2.2.1

Tags: exm, sitecore-forms

In Sitecore 9.1.1 XP1 on CM server

Forms Extension 2.2.1, Send Email submit action gives error:

```
ERROR Object reference not set to an instance of object.
Exception: System.NullReferenceException
Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source: Feature.FormsExtensions
    at Feature.FormsExtensions.SubmitActions.SendEmail.SendEmailBase`1.SendMail(ContactIdentifier toContact, Dictionary`2 customTokens, Guid message)
    at Feature.FormsExtensions.SubmitActions.SendEmail.SendEmailBase`1.Execute(T data, FormSubmitContext formSubmitContext)
```

Forms Extension works fine on our XP0 test server.

I really have no idea where to start to look. Any ideas?

Comment: Does your form have dropdownlist/checkboxlist type fields ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Send Email` submit action fails on CM because the Email Experience Manager Client API is intended to run only on Content Delivery instances. The purpose of this client API is to proxy the requests to add or remove contacts from a List Manager list, or to send EXM campaigns from the Content Delivery instances to the Content Management instances.

The `SendMail` method is indeed failing on this line: https://github.com/bartverdonck/Sitecore-Forms-Extensions/blob/master/src/Feature/FormsExtensions/code/SubmitActions/SendEmail/SendEmailBase.cs#L63

```
clientApiService.SendAutomatedMessage(automatedMessage);
```

The failure of the send email submit action is then expected on a Content Management server in a scaled topology. You should validate its functionality on the Content Delivery instances only.